# Download xml file from FTP

Tags: ftp, download, automation

I want script to download xml file from ftp, already written small script for it and seems working fine, while running the script from command prompt ftp -s:script.txt. Is it possible to keep the script.txt file in some other drive and run it.

Because my script is in D\scripts drive and my command prompt defaults me to C drive,
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you can specify the full path:

```
ftp -s:D:\somepath\script.txt
```

be careful to use quotes should the path contain spaces:

```
ftp -s:"D:\some path with spaces\script.txt"
```